# How do i make a button dropdown while hovering?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, dropdown, navbar

We have to make a project at school and i want to make this dropdown inside a navbar expand once you hover it. I've tried diffrent solutions but so far all I get is a button that requires a click or all the options beneath each other without a dropdown.

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <div class="dropdown" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Category</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Login</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using CSS, and Bootstrap.

Here is a working example.

```css
@import url('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');


.container {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0;
 }
```

```html
       <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container"> 
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Link</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#opening">Link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
    
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: thank you so much!
literally just copy/paste it and it works.
you are a fricking legend

Answer (score 1):

It does not need a framework

You could simply use `:hover` pseudo-class and chlid combinator(`>`)

The following provides three ways to implement a drop-down menu using css

```css
.nav-item a{
  display: block;
}


.dropdown-menu-1 {
  display: none;
}

li.dropdown-1:hover>.dropdown-menu-1 {
  display: block;
}


/****** OR *******/

.dropdown-menu-2 {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li.dropdown-2:hover>.dropdown-menu-2 {
  height: auto;
}

/****** OR *******/

.dropdown-menu-3 {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

li.dropdown-3:hover>.dropdown-menu-3 {
  opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav">
  <li class="nav-item dropdown-1">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown">Category</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu-1">
      <a>Login</a>
      <a>Another action</a>
      <a>Something else here</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown-2">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown">Category</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu-2">
      <a>Login</a>
      <a>Another action</a>
      <a>Something else here</a>
    </div>
  </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown-3">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown">Category</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu-3">
      <a>Login</a>
      <a>Another action</a>
      <a>Something else here</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```